# Decimal values of Extended ASCII characters

Tags: c++, character-encoding, internationalization, ascii

I wrote a function to test if a string consists only of letters, and it works well:

```
bool is_all_letters(const char* src) {
  while (*src) {
    // A-Z, a-z
    if ((*src>64 && *src<91) || (*src>96 && *src<123)) {
      *src++;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

My next step was to include “Extended ASCII Codes”, I thought it was going to be really easy but that’s where I ran into trouble.  For example:

```
std::cout << (unsigned int)'A' // 65          <-- decimal ascii value
std::cout << (unsigned int)'ñ'; // 4294967281 <-- what?
```

I thought that the decimal value for ‘ñ’ was going to be 164 as listed on the ASCII chart at  www.asciitable.com.

My goal is to restrict user input to only letters in ISO 8859-1 (latin 1). I’ve only worked with single byte characters and would like to avoid multi-byte characters if possible.

I am guessing that I can compare the unsigned int values above, i.e.: 4294967281, but it does not feel right to me and besides, I don’t know if that large integer is VC 8.0 representation of 'ñ' and changes from compiler to compiler.

Please advise

**UPDATE** - Per some suggestions made by Christophe, I ran the following code:

```
locale loc("spanish") ;
cout<<loc.name() << endl;                   // Spanish_Spain.1252
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
  cout << i << " " << isalpha(i, loc)<< " " << (isprint(i,loc) ? (char)(i):'?') << endl; 
}
```

It does return Spanish_Spain.1252 but unfortunately, the loop iterations print the same data as the default C locale (using VC++ 8 / VS 2005).

Christophe shows different (desired) results as you can see in his screen shots below, but he uses a much newer version of VC++.

Comment: ASCII only goes from 0 to 127. Beyond that is a giant mess. Even within that range is enough of a mess from other encodings like EBCDIC.

Comment: Better to work in Unicode.

Comment: First cast to `unsigned char` then cast to `unsigned int`. Then you should see the value you would expect.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish No, I don't think you will.

Comment: Cast to (int) instead and it will be a bit more obvious that `char` is a signed type.  And yes, the character code for ñ is 0xf1 in many code pages, including Windows 1252 and ISO 8859-1.

Comment: Has no one asked about the encoding of the tty?

Comment: What encoding is your source code saved with?

Comment: @HansPassant char may be signed or unsigned.  That's implementation defined.

Comment: @Christophe It is somewhat obvious OP uses a signed char.

Comment: @HansPassant, I don't understand why the '±' is displayed:   char* p = "ñ";  std::cout << p;

Comment: @CarolineBeltran  if you encode ñ in a windows text editor, it's one encoding.  If you write to the console, it will use the code page of the console, which is another encoding.

Comment: `±` is 0xf1 in code page 437, the default code page for console mode apps.  Does Unicode start sounding attractive yet?  Use SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8) to switch to utf-8, use the console window system menu to change the font to, say, Consolas.

Comment: @HansPassant, unicode sounds scary but I may have to study that. I was hoping for an easy way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There  is already plenty of information here. However, I'd like to propose some ideas to adress your inital problem, being the categorisation of extended character set.

For this, I suggest the use of [`<locale>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/) (country specific topics), and especially the new locale-aware form of [isalpha()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isalpha/), isspace(), isprint(), ...  .

Here a little piece of code to help you to find out what chars could be a letter in your local alphabet:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));               // sets the environment default locale currently in place 
std::cout << std::locale().name() << std::endl;     // display name of current locale 

std::locale loc ;                                   // use a copy of the active global locale (you could use another)
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    cout << i << " " << isalpha(i, loc)<< " " << (isprint(i,loc) ? (char)(i):'?') << endl; 
}
```

This will print out the ascii code from 0 to 255,  followed by an indicator if it is a letter according to the local settings,  and the character itself if it's printable.

FOr example, on my PC,  I get:
[image: screenshot because of char encoding differences] 
And all the accented chars, as well as ñ, and greek letters are considered as alpha, whereas £ and mathematical symbols are considered as non alpha printable.

Comment: I built your code on VC++ 8 and for some reason unknown to me, I am getting "English_United States.1252" even though Windows on my computer is Windows 7 running the Spanish language and locale. I'm starting to wonder if there is some kind of limitation to VC++ 8 because I try to set the locale and I can't seem to do it, i.e.: std::locale ("en_US.UTF8" ); // exception.  In a nutshell, I am only able to use the "English_United States.1252" local, don't understand why this is.

Comment: I see.  Try the following change in the code: `std::locale loc("spanish") ;`.  (and `cout<<loc.name()<<endl`.  I got spanish and consistent resutls with MSVC13. Locale names other than "" and "C" appear library dependent, and I've found this guy who played around with windows:  http://xoax.net/cpp/ref/cstd/incl/clocale/fn/setlocale/

Comment: I think that my Locale problem is caused by VC++ 8, I updated my original post detailing why.  I do believe that using the locale class would have been the easiest solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The code chart you found on the internet is actually Windows [OEM code page 437](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305156), which was never endorsed as a standard. Although it is sometimes called "extended ASCII", that description is highly misleading. (See [the Wikipedia article *Extended ASCII*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII): "The use of the term is sometimes criticized, because it can be mistakenly interpreted that the ASCII standard has been updated to include more than 128 characters or that the term unambiguously identifies a single encoding, both of which are untrue."

You can find the history of OEM437 on Wikipedia, in various versions.

What was endorsed as a standard 8-bit encoding is [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1), which later became the first 256 code points in [Unicode](http://unicode.org/). (It's one of a series of 8-bit encodings designed for use in different parts of the world; ISO-8859-1 is specified to the Americas and Western Europe.) So that's what you will find in most computers produced in this century in those regions, although more recently more and more operating systems are converting to full Unicode support.

The value you see for `(unsigned int)'ñ'` is the result of casting the ISO-8859-1 code `0xF1` from a (signed) `char` (that is, -15) to an `unsigned int`. Had you cast it to an `int`, you would have seen -15.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought that the decimal value for ‘ñ’ was going to be 164 as listed on the ASCII chart at www.asciitable.com.

Asciitable.com appears to give the code for the old [IBM437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) DOS character set (still used in the Windows command prompt), in which `ñ` is indeed 164.  But that's just one of *hundreds* of “extended ASCII” variants.

The value 4294967281 = 0xFFFFFFF1 you got is a sign-extension of the (signed) `char` value 0xF1, which is how `ñ` is encoded in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and close variants like [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you're trying to reinvent `std::isalpha`. But you'll need to pass the ISO-8859-1 locale IIRC, by default that just checks ASCII.

The behavior you see is because `char` is signed (because you didn't compile with `/J`, which is the smart thing to do when you use more than just ASCII - VC++ defaults to signed char).

Comment: The question was not tagged with `windows` so what does `/J` have to do with it ?

Comment: @trojanfoe: VC8 was explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @MSalters, I tried the isalpha function (not std) originally but it only worked with ascii decimal values up to 127 so I assumed that std::isalpha() would be similar.  I tried unsigned like this but got an error:   unsigned char* p = "ñ"; // error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [2]' to 'unsigned char *'

Comment: @CarolineBeltran: The `std::` optionally takes a locale, which _might_ fix it. But `"ñ"` is a `const char[2]`, not a single char. (Just as any "" string literal can't be passed to isalpha)